# using angularjs $filter() inside directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to hide some part of the input text value using some filter.

```
app.directive('limtToDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, ielem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
            $filter('limitTo')(ielem.val(), -5);
        });
    }
}}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PqAhk/2/

well, my input text should just show  12:12  instead of 01/01/1970 12:12. and after editing the time, for example, if user change the time to 12:40 my ng-model has to be like following 1970/01/01 12:40

Comment: I guess limitTo limits the array to a specific length. Can you elaborate what are you trying to do in this line.
$filter('limitTo')(ielem.val(), -5);

Comment: what, i realy want is just hidding the first part of the date "1970/01/01" and show the rest of the text value.                   for example if i change the time to 12:40 my ng-model will be equal 1970/01/01 12:40

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you all, this solution was created by @guru and many thanks to him.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VhsleIWMq8A4rJcVQDaw?p=preview

the solution takes advantage from  $formatter and $parser related to the angularjs pipeline rendering.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

ps : this solution is not compatible with angularjs.2-rc.x

Answer (score 0):

The filter in the link function -> `$filter('limitTo')(ielem.val(), -5);` filters the array and returns a new array with the filtered values. It has to be assigned back to the scope variable for the changes to get reflected.

Something like below.
    $scope.filteredValue= $filter('limitTo')(ielem.val(), -5);

Thats intersting. Though formatting can be easy by using $formatter in the ngModelCtl syncing the input data change back to the model can be tricky.
You can use the `ngModelCtl.$parsers` and `ngModelCtl.$formatters` to set up the format and view value.

Here is a working Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/1KqLsIwGJjwUIbs0fwmQ?p=preview

Comment: it works by adding the following line ielem. val ($filter ('limitTo') (ielem. val (), -5)); but this will affect my ng-model to be equal to 12.14 and what I want is just I hide the letter 190/01/01. @Jacob Goulden what I have to do sir after your post improvement, should I edit my post?

Comment: Thats intersting. Though formatting can be easy by using $formatter in the ngModelCtl syncing the input data change back to the model can be tricky.
You can use the ngModelCtl.$parsers and ngModelCtl.$formatters to set up the format and view value.
Here is a working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/1KqLsIwGJjwUIbs0fwmQ?p=preview

Comment: hi, it's wonderfull, but when i use it in my project, i got NAN:NAN. and the formatValue is Undefined, if you can explain to me how it work i will gratefull :)

Comment: $formatters - has a array of functions used to format value for display purpose
$parsers - has a array of functions used to populate value to the actual model linked.
Further Reading: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: If possible post your non working code in plunker. I will check if I can help with that

Comment: the problem is caused by the version of my angularjs. i am using 1.2.rc-2 http://plnkr.co/edit/ralLAjvYzyzjp9eLAhQG?p=preview        another problem, when i am using your solution and i  set a letter in the text field it set the ng-model to  NaN/NaN/0NaN NaN:NaN

Comment: 1.2.16 is the latest stable version. Looks like there are some problems with 1.2.rc2. I will suggest to use the stable version instead of an rc version. 
the time in the input file has to be of format 'hh:mm' for this to work properly. Though you can use a regex in the parser and formatter to check whether its in the specific format if not revert back to the old value

Comment: I've updated the plunker to check for value format. Please refer to
http://plnkr.co/edit/1KqLsIwGJjwUIbs0fwmQ?p=preview

Comment: I would suggest not to use rc versions in your app. Instead use the latest versions or the closest stable versions to the rc. For instance 1.2.1 is the closest one where the error does not occur. The latest stable version is 1.2.16 which I would recommend to use. rc versions are supposed to use for testing the new feautures and not ideal for production use.

Comment: thank you guru, i want to know if there is some problem between minor release? if yes, what i have to take care about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your model to change then don't use two way binding:

```
<div ng-app = "fiddle">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
        <table class="table">
            <input type="text" ng-value="fromDate | limitTo:-5" />
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Better yet why not make from date a real date object:

```
$scope.fromDate = new Date(); // current date for demonstration, set to real value
```

And use the date filter:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="fromDate | date:'HH:mm'" />
```

Comment: i have updating my question to be much more clear. what i really want is just using filter to hide some part of the text value. in my case it will be "1970/01/01" but my ng-model should remain "1970/01/01 12:12" and if user edit time to 12:40 this will update my ng-model to follow "1970/01/01 12:40"